# Select tag flick on single click

Tags: angularjs, html, select, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image]

When I click on dropdown once it's flicker multiple time and then settle down not getting main cause of this issue. I am not able to debug this. 
Application is build using angular, bootstrap.

Note: This is happening in chrome for mac os.

Comment: we can't really do anything for you if don't provide us with useful information. the issue can be caused from many different reasons so posting some code or a plunk/fiddle that reproduces the problem with help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an Angular specific question. As a temporary solution remove transition from select control since Chrome 50.X and bootstrap 3.X.

```
select.form-control {
  transition: none;
}
```